# Keras custom fit_generator for numeric dataframe

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I have several CSV files which are placed in a directory. What I want to do is to create a flow from this directory where each file is taken, prepossessed(such as null value fill, outlier treatment etc) and then each data point is passed to keras model and this process should repeat itself for every file placed in the directory. Any suggestions on this to create data flow same as for Image data available in keras. Also this should happen in python :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Keras natively supplies such functionality.

You should make your own converter, using something like `glob` to go over each file, send it to preprocessing functions, and finally save it as a format readily usable by Keras, such as a numpy array.

You might want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120931/the-loss-and-accuracy-of-this-lstm-both-drop-to-nearly-0-at-the-same-epoch) for an example of inputting multiple files (although in this case they are already numpy arrays, not csv files) to use in the training of a model.

Comment: It seems to put me into same issue, the load cannot happen at once in RAM since data is huge in size. I want to build a pipeline which can keep on loading small files,preprocess on CPU and fed to model getting trained on GPU.

Comment: If each single csv is small enough to be loaded on its own, first write a non-Keras based script to translate each such file to a numpy array, then build a generator (train_generator, validation generator) that will make use of the files.

Comment: rather saving every small file into numpy array can i call the fit method for every file after pre processing it? will it reset the weights of the model or will it train from where it stopped in last iteration?

Comment: You could write something like that, but I do not recommend it at all.